# How do I properly print a substring after it's been reversed

Tags: c

So I'm doing a program where I have to reverse two substrings seperated by a space. I have a main reverseString function that is meant to call on a seperate reverse function, which calls on a stringlength function I made. This is the code I have so far

```
char string_length(char *pointer)
{
    int c = 0;  //The first element of our string

    while(*(pointer + c) !='\0')    //Uses order of operations to derefence the whole array
    {
        c++;        //Increments the offset and adds to the memory address of the pointer
    }

        return c;
}
char reverseFunc(char *s)
{
    int length, c;
    char *begin, *end, temp;

    length = string_length(s);  //We assign pointers
    begin = s;
    end = s;

    for(c=0; c<length-1; c++)   //We subtract one from the null terminator and get to the last character in the string
        end++;

    for(c=0; c<length/2; c++)   //We do the standard swap for reversal
    {
        temp = *end;
        *end = *begin;
        *begin = temp;

        begin++;
        end--;
    }
}
int revStr(char *revptr)
{
    int counter;
    int i;
    char subStr1[100];
    char subStr2[100];
    char *subptr1 = subStr1;
    char *subptr2 = subStr2;
    printf("Enter two strings seperated by a space: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", revptr);

    printf("\n%s\n", revptr);

    for(i=0; revptr[i] != ' '; i++)
    {
        subptr1[i] = revptr[i];
        counter++;
    }


    reverseFunc(subptr1);

    printf(" %s", subptr1);


}
```

Is there something up with my printf's or functions that's not allowing the substring to print properly

***Edit:***
Someone asked me for the calling function, the intended output and the actual output, which is what I'm putting below, respectively:

```
char selectMenu(char *revptr, char *multptr, char *conptr)  //This function must be at the bottom. Otherwise, it cannot call any function, as none 
                                                            //exist before it
{
    char select;        //Variable to determine which option user has selected
    do
    {
        printf("\nMagic with Strings!\n");          //Initial options user will see
        printf("1. Reverse a string\n");
        printf("2. Multiply a string\n");
        printf("3. Convert a string to numbers\n");
        printf("4. Exit\n");
        printf("Your selection is: ");
        scanf("%c", &select);
        printf("\n");

        switch(select)              //Switch statement redirecting user to a different function depending on what they've selected
        {

            case '1':
                revStr(revptr);
                return(0);

            case '2':
                multStr(multptr);
                return(0);

            case '4':
                return(0);
                    break;

            default:
                printf("\nPlease select an available option\n\n");

        }
    }while(select!=4);
}
```

My calling function is a menu with switch cases

```
Please enter two strings sperated by a space: Power Time
Rewop Emit
```

The strings are actually supposed to keep the uppercase in it's original spot, but that's for later

```
Enter two strings seperated by a space: Geo Oeg

 ��oeG
```

**Edit 2:**
A solution someone answered with worked perfectly. I know want to reverse the second substring with another for loop. This is what I have directly after what I just posted

```
for(i=0; revptr[i] != ' '; i++)
    {
        subptr1[i] = revptr[i];
        counter++;
    }

   subptr1[i] = '\0';

    reverseFunc(subptr1);

    printf(" %s\n", subptr1);

    counter++;

    for(i=0; revptr[counter] != '\0'; counter++, i++)
    {
        subptr2[i] = revptr[counter];
    }

    reverseFunc(subptr2);

    printf("%s\n", subptr2);
```

and the output:

```
Enter two strings seperated by a space: leek keel
 �keel
V.leek
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code that calls the `revStr` function as well as the input, expected output and actual output?

Comment: The strings need a null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from two small but important points ,both in `int revStr(char *revptr)`.

First using uninitialized `int counter` and second not adding `\0` to terminate `subptr1` 
which will affect `string_length` in other function too.

```
int revStr(char* revptr)
{
    int counter=0;
    int i;
    char subStr1[100];
    char subStr2[100];
    char* subptr1 = subStr1;
    char* subptr2 = subStr2;
    printf("Enter two strings seperated by a space: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", revptr);

    printf("\n%s\n", revptr);

    for (i = 0; revptr[i] != ' '; i++)
    {
        subptr1[i] = revptr[i];
        counter++;
    }
    subptr1[i] = '\0';

    reverseFunc(subptr1);

    printf(" %s", subptr1);


}
```